# Creating an Inverse Kinematics Service from MoveIt!

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, moveit, ikfast

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I have got my hydraulic arm successfully able to be controlled from MoveIt! and IKFast as per the scenario in http://answers.ros.org/question/190808/using-moveit-to-control-the-end-of-a-hydraulic-arm-in-cartesian-coordinates/ , but I can't find the steps for creating a service where I issue a request consisting of Cartesian Coordinates as an input and getting joint angles as an output. There is some stuff about the [PR2 arm](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_kinematics/Tutorials/Tutorial%204), but I can't work out how to adapt this for my arm.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Kind Regards
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194323/creating-an-inverse-kinematics-service-from-moveit!/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> but I can't find the steps for creating a service where I issue a request consisting of Cartesian Coordinates as an input and getting joint angles as an output.

Are you trying to implement your own service, or do you want to use an existing service, which does this for *your robot*?

If the latter, would the [GetPositionIK](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/moveit_msgs/html/srv/GetPositionIK.html) service from the `move_group` MoveIt capability work for your use case? Afaik, for the service to work, you should just launch a MoveIt configuration for your arm, populate a `moveit_msgs/GetPositionIK` with the appropriate info, and invoke the service.

Note that invoking services incurs quite some overhead, so depending on your use case, you might want to look into the MoveIt [Kinematics/C++ API](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Kinematics/C%2B%2B_API). The tutorial should give you enough information on how to use it with your particular robot/urdf.

> There is some stuff about the [PR2 arm](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_kinematics/Tutorials/Tutorial%204), but I can't work out how to adapt this for my arm.

That tutorial seems to have been written when `arm_navigation` was still used. I think (but am not sure) you'll have to adapt that quite a bit to get it working with MoveIt.

---

Edit: with a normal MoveIt configuration for your robot, you should see:

```
[..]
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
[..]
```

in your console, which should give you access to the `/compute_fk` and `/compute_ik` services (as I wrote in my original answer). Does this not cover your use case?

I merely mentioned the C++ interface so you'd know about it: it has much less overhead than a ROS service, and with about 4 to 5 lines of initialisation (see the tutorial I linked), I'm guessing it will be around the same programming effort as setting up and working with a `ros::ServiceClient`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-10-12**:
I want to implement whatever's the quickest and takes the least work. I already have the `move_group` node so if possible I'd like to take advantage of that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-13**:
See my edit: with a properly configured MoveIt configuration, there is nothing for you to implement.

**Comment by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on 2014-10-21**:
Thanks, I note though that using the move_group node as is also leaves in a lot of unneeded functionality. Is there a guide for what functionality that can be removed?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-22**:
Aren't you using MoveIt already? The `MoveGroupKinematicsService` should be loaded automatically then.

You can remove *capabilities* to load from the `capabilities` parameter, which is set in `launch/move_group.launch` of your MoveIt cfg pkg. But all those are generally needed.